# Unable to Refresh listview item in PhoneGap Android Application

Tags: android, listview, cordova, refresh, jquery-mobile-listview

I am using a dynamically created list. When a list its is clicked it should highlighted by changing it's data theme. I am doing this to achieve the objective:

```
$('#' + AudioNo).attr('data-theme','b');
$('#' + AudioNo).listview('refresh');
```

However the list doesn't refresh and the theme doesn't change (from e to b).

Using the following command also shows that data-theme has changed to 'b', but I can't see the visual impact of change of color:

```
alert ($('.MainMenu').html() );
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

==== EDIT ======

This is how the list itself is created:

```
    mTitle = "My Title";
gHtml +=   '<li data-role=list-divider>' + mTitle + '</li>';
for ( x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
    gHtml +=   '<li data-icon=arrow-r id="' + x + '" data-theme=""' + '>';
    gHtml +=      '<a name="' + x + '">' + "Title" + x + '</a>';
    gHtml +=   '</li>';

}

$('.MainMenu').empty();
$('.MainMenu').append(gHtml);
$('.MainMenu').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: use $('#' + AudioNo).trigger('create');$('#' + AudioNo).listview('refresh');

Comment: No change. In fact I have noticed that if I move the mouse away from the item and return the focus back then the theme change is shown. Otherwise it doesn't show instantly. Any idea?

Comment: event does't execute , need to check your js , because "trigger", create used to execute css to apply runtime.

Comment: I have modified the post to provide the Script that generates the list in the first place.

Comment: Are you referring to this:

$('.MainMenu').append(gHtml).trigger('create');

Comment: my posted code work with theme b , I have tested...

Comment: theme b (or any theme) works for me as well. What doesn't work is when I make a change later on (on click event) then it doesn't get refreshed.

I have now changed the logic and redisplaying the list instead of refreshing a single item, which appears to be working. Thanks for your time any way :-)

Comment: Working or not ... any theme..welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.MainMenu').empty();
var gHtml = "";
var mTitle = 'My Title';
gHtml =  '<li data-role="list-divider">' + mTitle + '</li>';
for ( var x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
      gHtml +=   '<li data-icon=arrow-r id="' + x + '" data-theme="b">';
      gHtml +=      '<a name="' + x + '">' + 'Title' + x + '</a>';
      gHtml +=   '</li>';

 }                      
 $('.MainMenu').append(gHtml).trigger('create');
 $('.MainMenu').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh any jQuery mobile list view using:

```
$('#'+list_id).trigger('create');
$('#'+ list_id).listview('refresh');
```

you may want to read this [conversation](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-listview-listview-refresh) about your issue.